# Implicit FTPS with Alpakka FTP

Tags: ftps, apache-commons-net, alpakka

I use Alpakka FTP 3.0.3 that uses internally Apache Commons Net 3.8.
I want to upload a file with FTPS inluding implicit SSL.
For FTPS without implicit SSL I use the following code:

```
FtpCredentials ftpCredentials = FtpCredentials.create(user, password)
FtpsSettings.create(inetAddress)
  .withPort(port)
  .withPassiveMode(true)
  .withBinary(true)
  .withCredentials(ftpCredentials)
  .withConfigureConnectionConsumer((FTPSClient ftpsClient) -> {
    ...
  }))
```

But there is no option to set implicit ssl. Please note, there is the option to modify the FTPSClient but the flag `isImplicit` inside FTPSClient is final.

For direct usage of Apache Commons Net I could use

```
new FTPSClient(true)
```

But in Alpakka the object is already created internally.
On the command line with lftp I can use `ftp:ssl-force true`.

Therefore, I tried that inside `withConfigureConnectionConsumer()`

```
ftpsClient.sendCommand("ftp:ssl-force", "true");
```

But that has no effect. I failed with the initial connect timeout.

> IO operation was stopped unexpectedly after 0 bytes because of java.io.IOException: Timed out waiting for initial connect reply